# Uma lógica em php

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou criando um sistema e quero, de forma segura, garantir que meu usuário só poderá fazer cinco postagens no banco de dados, ou seja, no site. Que lógica eu usaria para fazer esse tipo de permissão? Grato.

Comment: Contar quantos registros há e, se não houverem 5 ainda, permitir o cadastro; caso contrário, não permitir.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson. Mas como eu faria isso? É que sou leigo. Eu faço um if pegando o valor que tem no banco? É que eu não sei como fazer essa query

Comment: Depende muito da sua aplicação. Como está estruturada a tabela no banco? Como você identifica qual usuário está acessando a aplicação?

Comment: Tenho uma tabela chamada postagens e nela tem um campo onde eu envio o id do usuário

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione esses detalhes. A estrutura da tabela, incluindo a configuração das colunas, e como está gerenciando o usuário com PHP, se está armazenando em sessão, qual é o código, etc.

Comment: Ok, só um momento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz um select antes de abrir o campo de postagem para verificar quantas postagens ele ja fez.

Se vc quiser q seja 5 postagens por dia, faz um campo de data no banco de dados, para fazer a contagem de quantas postagens foi feitas naquela mesma data.

Um select simples ja resolveria.

Algo mais ou menos assim:

`SELECT count(id_usuario) as contador FROM suatabela WHERE data = datadehoje`

depois um if com o resultado

`if (contador >= 5) { echo 'ja atingiu o limite'; } 
  else { include('formdepostagem.php'); }`

Creio que seja essa a logica q vc busca. Se não for, tenta dar mais detalhes.

Comment: Isso resolve @FernandoVR. Obrigado

Comment: Magina amigo, tamo junto ^_^